# "Champion the paper" in peer-review communications

Tags: word-usage

I am a reviewer for a publication, and received the following message from the Editor:

> Does the authors' response address your concerns? Would you champion the paper?

Does "champion the paper" mean to accept the paper? Why use the word "champion" here? Is it some kind of convention?

---

Edits:  To clarify, I have received the same wordings on "champion" from different Editors.  It seems to me the usage of "champion", in this situation, is some kind of convention.

Comment: Lexico has [**champion**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/champion) VERB Vigorously support or defend the cause of. So I suppose that the editor is asking whether you would *promote* the paper, i.e. write a positive review.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for the hints.  Any thoughts on why would this word usage in this particular situation?  (Please see also my edits)

Comment: **Champion** is much stronger than **accept**.  The question is asking whether you would *actively* support this paper - e.g., cite it in your own research or recommend it to others.

Comment: @CanadianYankee  Yes, it seems to the right answer. Would you mind expanding your comments into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that "**Would you champion the paper?**" is meant as "**Would you support/stand by the paper?**".

*to champion sth* (verb) - [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/champion)

- to act as militant supporter of : UPHOLD, ADVOCATE

> He always **champions** the cause of the underdog.

- to protect or fight for as a champion

> He **championed** the ladies chivalrously in the tilts.